# "Enter PIN for Authenticator" for command ssh-add -K

Tags: authentication, ssh, yubikey

I am running into an issue in adding my .pem key to my `ssh-agent`. I have set up my Linux Ubuntu 20.04 system with Yubikey and it has worked great. Have not had any problems using my Yubikeys. Love the added security; however, when I run this specific command `ssh-add -K` I get this message `Enter PIN for authenticator:`. I typed in my pin number from my authenticator for GitHub and even pressed on my YubiKey but nothing processed through. Can anyone help me on this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the Apple version -K stores the password in your keychain, so you don't have to type it every time. In the non-Apple version -K "Loads resident keys from a FIDO authenticator".

So, Instead of writing

```
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/private_key
```

write this :

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_key
```

Replace private_key as your key
e.g. $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: heads up, using macos 10.15 here. if i use the `-K` switch with `ssh-add` it prompts me for a _PIN_ which i did not setup with this particular key that i'm attempting to add to my ssh-agent, so dropping the `-K` switch will prompt me for my passphrase. 